# Codeigniter mysql query with special characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, special-characters

Been struggling with this thing for hours now. Hopefully someone could help me out.

Trying to get data from mysql based on first and last name. Everything works just fine except when there is special characters like ä or ö.

I have the profiler on and query looks like this:

```
 SELECT mail, address, title FROM users WHERE firstname='teemu' AND lastname='sel%C3%A4nne'
```

And it should be:

```
SELECT mail, address, title FROM users WHERE firstname='teemu' AND lastname='selänne'
```

In my model it's like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT mail, address, title FROM users WHERE firstname=? AND lastname=?";
```

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Controller

```
        public function edit() 
    {
        $this->load->model('p_model');
$this->load->view('edit',$data);
  }

public function ajax_p($first,$last)
  {
        $this->load->model('p_model');

$data['info'] = $this->p_model->pInfo($first,$last);

$this->load->view('ajax/p',$data);
    }
```

Comment: and you get first and last name from form?

Comment: html encode the names before storing them or searching for them

Comment: Yep, I get first and last name from form. How could I achieve what I'm looking for by html encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do not forget to urldecode the post values. What might be happening is that you use $_POST instead of the codeigniter function $this->input->post(); $_POST won't urldecode the parameters for you while the codeigniter function does.

So verify that the variable you pass to your query really is selänne and not sel%C3%A4nne

And if it is sel%C3%A4nne, use urldecode() or $this->input->post()

Comment: I am using jQuery&AJAX for getting that info. `$( "#find" ).click(function(event) {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val().replace(/[ ]/g, "/");
  var name = "/" +name
  alert(name);
  $("#formajax").load("<?php echo site_url('default/ajax_p');?>"+ name);
  
  });`

Comment: alert(name); shows /teemu/selänne but url no change. I have also made that change: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:@_\-ä';

Comment: could you post your controller?

Comment: Result: sel%C3%A4nne & selänne but still query shows first one. Aaaah. My mistake :D This one works! Thanks x10000!

Comment: urldecode('sel%C3%A4nne') should be selänne are you sure you typed it correctly? Ah you editted, nice  :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you utf8_general_ci in database ?
And your file is encoded as utf8 ?

Comment: Yes to both. And I have tried different encodings in database too. :(

Answer (score 0):

try putting your special characters in config  like

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:@_\-ä';
```

and make sure your db is utf8_general_ci is your Server connection collation.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but how you do with single quote " ' "