# Codeigniter query with special character

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3 for my project. In my database i have a table that is being used by some other authentication system. the problem i am facing when i am am searching some value with special character (inside the data/ concated with the data)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = '$#!"."asdasd<3ddasd"."'";
```

Even **`$this->db->query($query);`** is not returning any desirable output. after `echo $this->db->last_query();` i get the query and it was as it should be. if i copy it to phpmyadmin, it gives correct result.

As per several discussion in SO and some other pages i have also tried with

- `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-!#@<$';`
- db is `utf8_general_ci` is Server connection collation.

Query i put here just for showing you a scenario and i have used active record.

EDIT 1: I have used $this->input->post() for getting the input.
EDIT 2: just found out doesnot work with **"$#!"."asdasd<3ddasd"** but work for **"$#!"."asdasd3ddasd"**

Comment: Surely the `$#!` need to be INSIDE the single quoted string

Comment: As `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value = $#!'asdasd<3ddasd'` is not a valid query

Comment: Ahh come on. ___No fixin the code after a comment is made___

Comment: misspelled in the query here.

Comment: problem is not with query syntax. this is why i fixed it. my original query is ok as it works with other rows that doesn't have special character. while giving in the SO i modified the query, this why error happened here :D. still thanks for pointing it.

Comment: your query is come from post method? if yes then i got it otherwise i hv another way to solve this

Comment: yes. from post method.

Comment: $this->input->post() is also post methods i guess...

Comment: `$this->db->last_query();` giving you right query!! then there is only one thing that you did mistake some where. Include your code here

Comment: thing is if i made mistake in the code then should it not affect for other input. currently i found i am having the problem only when i have (<) inside a input.

Comment: I would question the value of an authentication system that outputs apostrophes and quotes. Both pose a serious security risk. If it has to be used, have you tried raw encoding/decoding and making sure that the global_xss setting in the config is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not forget to urldecode the post values. What might be happening is that you use `$_POST` instead of the codeigniter function `$this->input->post();`

`$_POST` won't urldecode the parameters for you while the codeigniter function does.

So verify that the variable you pass to your query really is selänne and not `sel%C3%A4nne`

And if it is `sel%C3%A4nne`, use `urldecode()` or `$this->input->post()`

Reference from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995707/codeigniter-mysql-query-with-special-characters)

Comment: i have used $this->input->post()